# Why is there a syntax error 'Unexpected token' for Disqus Universal Code (ReactJS)?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, disqus, react-router-redux

I am simply trying out Disqus for the first time and trying to use the Universal Code but I am getting the following error:

[image]
Following is the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { Divider } from 'material-ui'

const styles = {
  title:{
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'left',
  marginLeft: 30
 }
}

export default class FirstPage extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div id="disqus_thread"></div>
        <script>
        (function() { // DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
        var d = document, s = d.createElement('script');

        s.src = '//karmaproject.disqus.com/embed.js';

        s.setAttribute('data-timestamp', +new Date());
        (d.head || d.body).appendChild(s);
        })();
        </script>
        <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the <a   href="https://disqus.com/?ref_noscript" rel="nofollow">comments powered by Disqus.</a></noscript>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What program is giving you the syntax error? Is it the browser itself or some code editor? If it's a code editor I'd be inclined to say that the editor is wrong in this case.

Comment: @slebetman It is shown through terminal